# Are "Quizzes" allowed?

Tags: discussion, questions

Recently, I found a lot of questions that the asker already knew the answer,
which are called **"Quiz"**. [Example](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75542/a-rebus-ive-just-watched). [Another example](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75438/an-unfinished-rebus). [Third example](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/70237/a-short-rebus-comes-here).
[Fourth example](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/69808/first-attempt-at-a-rebus). [Fifth example](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/60358/my-simple-rebus).
Obviously, the creator of the question already knew the answer.

Were they really allowed?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Puzzling, but I wonder if quizzes are allowed.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Questions where the asker already knows the answer are definitely allowed. In fact, I think a majority of our questions are this type. All of *my* questions have been puzzles that I've personally constructed, except for maybe one or two.