# Is Puzzling SE the place for pub quizzes?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, on-topic

I frequently host pub quizzes and I sometimes wish to get some help on certain issues. It's not about "please give me questions on topic X" but rather good structures, alternative interpretations of common topics, how to set up particular categories and how to support them with tools.

I am aware that there are many websites dedicated to providing pub quiz questions and even whole quizzes but I create every quiz by hand and don't use other material unless I find it fitting. I am very interested in going off the beaten track and rely solely on anecdotal accounts from other quizzes people have been to or that I visit myself. I am looking for a place with people who take this seriously as well.

Arcade SE seems to be more about *playing* games rather than *creating* them. But Puzzling SE strikes me as being solely about puzzles (duh) which *can* of course be part of a pub quiz but not by definition.

The only reference about 'quiz' that I found on here was [Are "Quizzes" allowed?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6560/are-quizzes-allowed) which I  think is a different topic.

Comment: Could you perhaps list several specific example questions? I see you have outlined certain topics you are interested in, but it would be helpful to see specific manifestations of those topics.

Answer (score 2):

A question is on topic here if it is (1) a puzzle, or (2) about puzzles. (There are various other specific constraints -- e.g., we don't take questions that are from currently running competitive events -- but those are not likely to be relevant for you.)

The sorts of question you describe sound perfectly appropriate to me. (Maybe "how to support them with tools" is less so; it might depend on how puzzling-specific the questions are.)

I can't guarantee how anyone else would react to your questions, obviously, but from your description here I certainly wouldn't be likely to close them as off-topic.

Comment: Important note: two other categories of off-topic questions are *Too Broad* and *Primarily Opinion-Based*. For example, asking "What is a good pub quiz?" would probably be closed under POB, but asking "How can I group my pub quiz questions to achieve X, Y, but avoid Z?" would be answerable (with some subjectivity, but I think this would be [Good Subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/))